# openwrap and r#6.0

Tags: openwrap

I have just updated my resharper plugin to R#6.

My references are no longer being picked up from the wrap cache.

I have to set my references manually.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master branch of openwrap (2.0) now has support for ReSharper 6.

To use a private build of OpenWrap, to test the latest yourself:

To get the code, you can do the following:

If you already have pulled the code from OpenWrap:

```
cd path\to\openwrap
git pull origin master
```

otherwise

```
git clone http://github.com/openrasta/openwrap path\to\openwrap
cd path\to\openwrap
```

Then to build:

```
o build-wrap
o update-wrap openwrap -sys
```

Comment: @Seb, it looks like OpenWrap 1.0.1 doesn't support ReSharper 5.1.3. Are there plans to support it? Or is there a way to manually add such a support (as I don't think that there are many differences between R# 5.1.1 and 5.1.3)?

Comment: If it works with 5.1.1 it ought to work with 5.1.3. Can you fill a bug report with the exact version of resharper, visual studio you're using? It may be that the binaries don't match anymore for whatever reason, we can issue a patch for that on the old branch.

Comment: @Seb, I managed to solve the problem myself by copying OpenWrap.Resharper.511.dll to OpenWrap.Resharper.513.dll (i.e. I didn't change the assembly while copying, I just changed its name) within the openwrap-1.0.1.81349963.wrap file, everything's fine now.

Comment: That is a very, very strange fix for that bug! Still investigating what's going on there...